# Make pdf-tools highlight persist after searching

Tags: isearch, highlighting, pdf-tools

Is it possible to make the highlight of searched terms persist after pressing <kbd>RET</kbd>? I had liked very much the behavior of `zathura` in this aspect.

My question is :

Can `pdf-tools` be tweaked to have the same behavior of `isearch` with `isearch-lazy-highlight-cleanup` set to `nil`? (i.e. make highlighting persist after stop searching)

Comment: Please pose only one question per question. (And your second question, at the end, is anyway unclear. What do you mean by "looking for" the current highlight?)

Comment: There is no straight-forward way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about `pdf-tools`. But it sounds like you're just asking how to make Isearch's lazy highlighting persist after you stop searching.

If so, the answer to that is to set user option `lazy-highlight-cleanup` to `nil`. `C-h v` tells you:

> **`lazy-highlight-cleanup`** is a variable defined in `isearch.el`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Controls whether to remove extra highlighting after a search.
>
> If this is `nil`, extra highlighting can be "manually" removed with
>   `M-x lazy-highlight-cleanup`.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: Thank you, that's the behaviour I'm looking for but in `pdf-tools`. Unfortunately, `lazy-highlight-cleanup` doesn't have an effect on `pdf-tools`. I removed the second question because `pdf-tools` does highlight differently current match and other matches. The sole issue now, is to make it persist. The answer should reside in `pdf-isearch` but I'm relatively new with emacs.